# How can I browse the local network from a web client using C#?

Tags: c#, javascript

Our web client needs a way to browse the local network and select location for file storage.  This will then be returned to the webpage as a UNC name.

On a native client this easily accomplished by using Shell32 functions.

I've looked at ASP FileUpload, but that returns the file vs. a specific directory.

EDIT:  Another option would be to execute this on the clientside using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If by "web client", you mean a web browser - then you really can't. There's an [HTML file input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535263(VS.85).aspx), but it requires a file (which is no doubt what ASP FileUpload was using). There's [Shell.Application.BrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774065(VS.85).aspx) and you could [create your own](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5201) using [Scripting.FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50.aspx) - but those are Windows only, and would probably be locked down with security restrictions these days.

If you're willing to take a dependency on Flash or Silverlight, you could probably build or buy something in them. However, I don't think Silverlight has a built in control for it [(OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog.filter(VS.95).aspx) is the closest, but looks to also only allow selecting a folder).

Answer (score 0):

You actually *can* use the Shell32 functions in C#, see [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/).